# How to increment a secondary sequence number in a `delete from ... into` query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I'm a budding Pokemon card collector, and I use a SQL database to keep track of my cards. I assign each *kind* of Pokemon a number, `id`. I want to keep track of the *order* I collected each kind, so I also assign each card a sequence number `seqno`. I display the cards on a shelf.

```
create table shelf (
    kind_id int not null,
    seqno int not null
)

insert into shelf values (0, 1), 
                         (0, 2),
                         (0, 3),
                         (1, 1),
                         (1, 2)
```

I've only caught two kinds of Pokemon: three of the first kind and two of the second.

When I go collect more cards, I throw them in a bag.

```
create table bag (
    kind_id int not null,
)

insert into bag values (0),
                       (0),
                       (1),
                       (2)  -- woot, caught a new one
```

It's easy to move all my cards from the bag to the shelf...

```
delete from bag
output deleted.kind_id, -1
into shelf (kind_id, seqno)
select * from bag
```

...and then use `-1` to remind me to set the sequence number, but I'm tired of setting it manually.

I'm also a very type-A coder, and I don't want to write a second query to update the sequence numbers. I want it all to happen within the "move from bag to shelf" query.

The constraints sound odd, I know. I'm trying to distill a more complex problem, so hopefully the story helps.

Comment: Your first insert into shelf looks like 2 cards and you said it's one of the first kind and two of the second?  But it looks like 3 of the first and 2 of the second.  Also why do they share seqnum?  Shouldn't the values be more like `(0,1)(1,2)(1,3)`? Or are you wanting seqnum to only increment per id? Either way I'm confused on how 5 inserts = 3 cards (I get the 2 ids)

Comment: Don't delete from `bag`.  Add a `shelfId` column.  The bag contains those that are not `NULL`.

Comment: @Aaron Dietz You're right, 3 of the first, 2 of the second, thanks for catching that. And yes, I only want seqnum to increment per id, not across the whole table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, effectively creating a "shelved" flag, yes. That would be ideal. Unfortunately, I'm dealing with another (rather avid) collector and his insistence on placing new cards in a bag. In other words, the system is a bit too established to make those changes right now. But good suggestion.

Comment: what should bag look like after you are done?

Comment: @Paparazzi, it should be empty.

Comment: OK what should shelf look like

Comment: @Paparazzi, it should have additional rows `(0,4)(0,5)(1,3),(2,1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your delete-into to an insert then delete.  Use a subquery to find the `MAX(seqnum)` from shelf (correlated to the correct id) and increment it during the insert.  Wrap the subquery in `ISNULL('',1)` to start the seqnum at 1 for new cards, (or use a default value constraint on the seqnum column):

```
SELECT b.kind_id, 
       ISNULL(seqno + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.kind_id ORDER BY b.kind_id),1)
FROM bag b
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(seqno) seqno, kind_id
           FROM shelf
           GROUP BY kind_id) s on s.kind_id = b.kind_id
```

Then just `DELETE FROM bag`

Comment: The isnull function should default to 1.

Comment: This will duplicate sequence numbers when more than one card of a particular kind is in the bag. http://rextester.com/UJDGL4461

Comment: Whoops, let me fix that.

Comment: @mac9416 See new code.  By using row number to increment instead of a default 1, it should solve that issue.  Also switched the `ISNULL()` to default to 1 - I was looking at the default id of 0 for some reason.

Comment: Solid solution! I'm still curious whether it can be done in one query... but the limitations of `output` seem overwhelming.

Comment: @mac9416 Hmm I'd be curious to see it too.. Subqueries aren't allowed in the `OUTPUT` clause, so to my knowledge that wouldn't work.  Maybe `MERGE`, but I can't see how.  Anyway, I'm glad this solution works for you.  Consider using `TRUNCATE` instead of `DELETE` too.

Comment: Accepting because it doesn't seem a single-query solution is possible. Thanks for the still-elegant solution, @AaronDietz!

Answer (score 0):

windows function

```
select id 
     , row_number over (partition by id, order by id) as autoSeqno 
from shelf
```

or just use bag for the base table and don't delete it